# Simple javascript for selecting random element out of array outputting "undefined" on 2 elements (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, innerhtml

Below is my code, for some reason it outputs `undefined` for `['6']` & `['7']`, all the other ones work. I don't understand what is going wrong.

```
var array = [
    ['1'],
    ['2'],
    ['3'],
    ['4'],
    ['5'],
    ['6']
    ['7'],
    ['8'],
    ['9'],
    ['10']
];

if(document.getElementById("random-element")) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    document.getElementById('random-element').innerHTML = rand;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggky7a03/

Comment: You missed the comma after ['6']

Comment: @htoniv Oh, wow. Can't believe I missed that (and that netbeans didn't give me any indication). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: well it was still valid which is why it didn't show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a comma in your array, which will explain why those 2 values are not returning (they don't exist)

Side note, `array` is a reserved word in JS, so you can't (shouldn't) use it for your variable name, so change it to

```
var myAwesomeArray = [ 
// or similar
```

Here's your [fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/x8oh9h9f/2/)

Comment: Imagine is real writers got this response from their editor: comma missing on page 127, book is unreadable :)